# How to use Jena SPARQL UUID?

Tags: sparql, uuid, jena

Is there a way to generate UUID's in SPARQL?  I'm using the Jena-Fuseki version.  I cannot use b-nodes.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since SPARQL 1.1 UUID generation is now part of the standard and has been supported in Jena ARQ for some time now.

The [UUID()](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-uuid) function will return a UUID as a URI

The [StrUUID()](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-struuid) function will return a UUID as a String

E.g.

```
SELECT (UUID() AS ?uuid) (StrUUID() AS ?strUuid) WHERE { }
```

Answer (score 2):

Jena's ARQ includes a number of built-in functions as SPARQL [extensions](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/extension.html#propertyFunctions), including a UUID generator.  Many of these functions are listed on the [Functions in ARQ](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/library-function.html) page of the ARQ documentation, though `uuid` is not.  Here's an example usage, with Jena's command line tools.  The following query is in a file called `query.sparql`.

```
prefix afn: <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/ARQ/function#>
prefix ex: <http://example.org/>

construct { 
  ?uuid a ex:UUID
}
where {
  BIND( afn:uuid() as ?uuid ) 
}
```

The `arq` command line tool needs an data input, so I created a blank file called `data.n3`.  The `construct` query returns an RDF graph that says the generated UUID is an `ex:UUID`.

```
$ arq --query query.sparql --data data.n3 
@prefix afn:     <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/ARQ/function#> .
@prefix ex:      <http://example.org/> .

<urn:uuid:295322a3-7eab-4e4c-b0a0-ca8ac77f3205>
      <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>
                    ex:UUID .
```

With a different serialization format:

```
$ arq --query query.sparql --data data.n3  --results RDF/XML
```

```xml
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:afn="http://jena.hpl.hp.com/ARQ/function#"
    xmlns:ex="http://example.org/">
  <ex:UUID rdf:about="urn:uuid:10c7c8f0-4154-4bbf-ab0c-c52a4196b804"/>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Comment: My answer is OK if you have to use a pre-1.1 version of SPARQL, but if you can use the current Jena and ARQ which support SPARQL 1.1, [RobV's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17244611/1281433) is better.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Jena seems to have provided a couple of functions at PREFIX afn: < http://jena.hpl.hp.com/ARQ/function#> -- afn:uuid() (returns an URN) and its counterpart afn:struuid().