# How to generate UUIDs for updates via SPARQL

Tags: sparql, uuid

Using an RDF database, accessed via a SPARQL endpoint, what's the best way of generating new UUID IRIs and using them for new resources?

Here is an overview of some approaches I've tried. I am sharing this because I would have liked to find this question answered. My favourite is the last approach, but I'd say it's still up for debate.

#### Generate a UUID in the client and using it in the Update request

- pro: fast
- con: you cannot be sure the UUID is unique in the database. The chance of a collision is small, though.

#### Generate a UUID in the client and check if the RDF store contains triples with that id. Iterate until the UUID is new.

- pro: you can be reasonably sure that the UUID is unique in the db (except for ones added in concurrent updates)
- con: quite slow

#### Ask the RDF store for a UUID and use it

Query: `SELECT (UUID() as ?id) WHERE{}`

- pro: UUID is guaranteed to be unique (i.e. not yet used) in the store
- con: it's an additional request (but it's a quick one)

#### Ask the RDF store for N >> 1 UUIDs before doing a bigger amount of updates

Query (returns 1000 result rows):

```
SELECT (UUID() as ?id) WHERE {
   VALUES ?index1 { 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 } 
   VALUES ?index2 { 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 } 
   VALUES ?index3 { 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 } 
}
```

- pro: Probably fastest per UUID if >> 1 are needed
- pro: UUIDs are guaranteed to be unused in the store
- con: this approach requires more client-side programming
- and: this is an unusual query, is there a better way to achieve this?

Related:

- [How to get UUID() from INSERT Sparql Request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57397790/how-to-get-uuid-from-insert-sparql-request)
- [How to use Jena SPARQL UUID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17241838/how-to-use-jena-sparql-uuid)
- [SPARQL CONSTRUCT+INSERT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62637167/sparql-constructinsert)

Comment: Any system generating UUIDs will be "practically unique" even if done in the client for any decent implementation (e.g. a proper entropy pool for version 4). Get verison1 (address + timestamp +epoch based) are unique (read the RFC for caveat) or for unpredicable ask for version4 (which are very large random numbers, 122 bits, so large that the probability of a clash is so small you need to worry about other things first, like the hardware or network silently corrupting data.) I doubt a store guarantees uniqueness. 2^122 is a very large number.

Comment: Thanks for putting that in perspective. Maybe the comparison with the probability of hardware or network corruption puts my mind at ease. Anyway, in the discussion to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57408993/6439655), [Jeen Broekstra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/451941/jeen-broekstra) said UUIDs are unique - maybe he meant it the way you formulated it - practically unique.

Comment: Indeed I did...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [AndyS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/757100/andys)'s comment, I decided to [look that up again](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Collisions) and adjust my expectations: you have to generate 1 billion UUIDs per second for about 85 years to reach a 50% probability of one or more collisions. Therefore, Variant 1 is best:

Generate a UUID in the client and use it in the update request.